# How to get a collection of objects of the same class posted back to controller with assigned html form values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, html.beginform

I have converted the edit function of a generated controller entity framework with views of my model. Instead of the edit handling one instance of my model at a time I send a list of all of my instances and loop through them in a `Html.BeginForm` in my razor view. When I post the form I try to pass the list as a parameter into my controller. I want a list of all the instances with all their the updated values however the list is posted as null. I cannot see that it is a markup issue. Please help.

Here is my controller:

```
public ActionResult Allotment(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    List<ClaimFile> claimFiles = db.ClaimFiles.Where(b => b.ClaimID == id).ToList();
    if (claimFiles.Count == 0)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    ViewBag.DocumentListID = new SelectList(db.DocumentLists, "DocumentListID", "Description", claimFiles.FirstOrDefault().DocumentListID);
    return View(claimFiles);
}
```

View:

```
@model List<Harry.ClaimFile>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <h4>ClaimFile</h4>
    <hr />
    @foreach (var claimfile in Model)
    {

        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => claimfile.ClaimFileID)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => claimfile.DocumentListID, "DocumentListID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("DocumentListID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => claimfile.DocumentListID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>


    }

    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
}
```

Then here on the post controller I receive null when I hit the save button on my razor view:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Allotment(List<ClaimFile> claimFiles)
{
    //List<ClaimFile> claimFiles = null. This is my problem
}
```

Please show me what I have done wrong or give a solution to this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried to send a list back to controller,

I saw [this](http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/b1e0b153-47f4-4b29-8583-958aa22d9284.aspx) article on net,maybe it's helpful.